# Less frequent dragon encounters on my second game?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have finished the game once and it was quiet boring afterwards so I just started a new game.

However, I have been noticing that there are a lot less dragon encounters on the new game.

Is there any reason to this?

Comment: How far into the new game are you? Do you have any of the DLCs, and have you played through any of them? I'm playing a second playthrough myself, but I could swear I'm dealing with *more* dragons than I used to. I'm a fair bit into the game though, have all DLCs, and have completed the primary Dragonborn questline.

Comment: @Iszi I don't have any DLC and I am at the part where you have to trap Ohdaaving.

Comment: How often do you fast-travel? I swear, it seems that's the time when they're most likely to show up.

Comment: @Iszi Well...... everytime I am doing a quest and a location on the map is closer to the objective. I don't fast-travel much in freeroam.

Comment: dragon encounters are random.

Answer (score 2):

Dragon encounters are entirely random in every game; while one playthrough will have you fight dragons until you're knee-deep in their dead, while another one will have you encounter only a few. I myself once had a game where I didn't encounter a single dragon (other than the story ones) until I was around level 20, to the point that I almost forgot there were dragons in the game.

There are [some areas](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Dragons_%28Skyrim%29#Locations), however, in which dragons are scripted to appear.